# How to organize projects on Git server?

Tags: git

I am fairly new to Git and I am moving from SVN. I am working on setting up a new Git server for my team. I am trying to understand the best way to setup projects on the Git server.

**Is each project that I want to branch and tag its own repo in Git?** In SVN, it would normally be its own folder in the central SVN repository. It seems Git prefers project to be their own isolated repository.

**If I am correct in assuming each project is a new repository in Git, how are things grouped?** In SVN, different teams may have a section of the SVN repo, with their projects under that section. Examples maybe grouping all frontend projects in one folder and all services in another. Is this done in Git by naming the te repo with a prefix or is there a concept of folders or groups?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each project is ideally its own repository. You can of course make a mega-lith repository of everything, but thats suboptimal.

I tend to make repositories in folders, and use `git submodule` to bring in libraries or dependencies into top-level projects. Submodule is a great way to version which iteration of an external repository you are using.

Answer (score 2):

First off, git is complex, but using github.com is a great way to understand it's strengths and to learn some of it's best practices.  It's the site that I used while learning, and it has some good documentation on git workflow, tricks, etc.  I recommend it as a way to move beyond the concepts that svn might have instilled that no longer apply.

As far as organization of the repo between teams, whatever would make the most sense in a folder on some server applies equally to git, because git will essentially duplicate the full folder that is the repository root at all times.

What may help is to have different teams work in different branches and rebase off of and push into a stable central branch frequently.  I currently use master branch for production-ready code, a dev branch for potentially unstable code that merits sharing and testing, but shouldn't go live yet and local branches whenever I think of a new feature to try out.